# How to emulate Firebase authentication without an API key

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-tools

I'm building an open-source project using Firebase's JS SDK. My goal is to allow contributors to run the project locally using the Firebase emulator so that they don't need any real credentials. The [Firebase emulator docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/connect_auth) specify that "you can run the emulators without ever creating a Firebase project". That's exactly what I want!

After running `firebase init`, I wrote up the following code. It triggers a popup that allows users to sign in through GitHub:

```ts
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { connectAuthEmulator, getAuth, GithubAuthProvider } from "firebase/auth";

const app = initializeApp({
  projectId: "demo-project",
});

const auth = getAuth(app);
connectAuthEmulator(auth, "http://localhost:9099");

// When users sign in, we call the following method:
async function signIn() {
  const githubAuth = new GithubAuthProvider();
  await signInWithPopup(firebaseClientAuth, githubAuth);
}
```

The code above will trigger the following error:

> Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: Firebase: Error (auth/invalid-api-key)

In the real world, I would call `initializeApp()` with an `apiKey`, but here I just want to emulate authentication. I've also tried not to call `initializeApp()` at all and call `getAuth()` without any arguments, but it triggers the same error.

Presumably, an API key requires creating a project, so is it actually possible to run the Firebase auth emulator without creating a Firebase project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is it actually possible to run the Firebase auth emulator without creating a Firebase project?

No, you need to have the emulator connected to a project.  You'll notice in the [setup instructions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/install_and_configure#install_the_local_emulator_suite) you are required to run `firebase init` to choose your project and the products you want to use in that project.

Comment: I didn't mention it in my question but I did run `firebase init` first. Even then, I'm still required to provide an API key -- is that right?

Comment: Yes, as far as I know you can't alter the SDK init process outside of what the documentation says you should do. You could always file a request on GitHub to see if this can be changed. https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is.

> A demo Firebase project has no real Firebase configuration and no live resources. These projects are usually accessed via codelabs or other tutorials.
> Project IDs for demo projects have the **demo-** prefix.
> [Firebase Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/connect_auth#environment-variable)

Run `firebase emulators:start --project demo-[ANYTHING_YOU_WANT]`

For example `firebase emulators:start --project demo-test-project`

Comment: But what object properties do I now need to pass to `initializeApp()`, besides the demo-prefixed project ID? apiKey, storageBucket, etc

Answer (score 0):

Let to the game here, but I've found I can avoid `auth/invalid-api-key` errors while using the emulators by simply passing `apiKey: "any-string-value"` to `initializeApp` in tests:

```js
initializeApp({ apiKey: "test-api-key" });
connectAuthEmulator(getAuth(), 'http://localhost:8081');
```

This seems to be tracked in this (open, but inactive) issue:
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/6776

> The check for apiKey is done on the client side, which was appended before the auth emulator was created, so it is probably not needed.
> https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/blob/master/packages/auth/src/core/auth/register.ts#L68-L71

Hope this is helpful to someone (very tricky to get answers to seemingly-simple things like this from the Firebase docs).